# Rails 4: nested resources -> nested models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, nested, ruby-on-rails-4

Today I upgraded from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and I noticed that when I tried to open the web browser there was an error saying `unitialized constant Foo::Bar`. The controller code in question looks something like

```
@foo = Foo.find(params[:foo])
@bars = @foo.bars # here the error occurs
```

My routes are simple: `resources :foo { resources :bar }`

I have switched to strong_params and thus have moved all `attr_accessible` to the controller params.

This nesting of models was not intentioned by me, Rails did that behind my back. When I actually moved `bar` into app/models/foo/bar.rb, it seemed to work which I find somewhat strange. I have searched the net to no avail.

Any explanations?

Comment: What associations do you have on your Foo model? `has_many :bars` ?

Comment: `has_many :bars` and `has_many :cars, through: :bars`

Comment: i have refactored back to the old flat models just now and rails has stopped complaining... is this a potential bug? Or did I do something wrong? I find this strange...

Comment: Strange. Sounds like you made a lot of changes at once. Can you narrow it down to just one?

Comment: Well it does work as expected now (without nested models) - when upgrading to Rails 4 I made all the changes that railscasts "Upgrading to Rails 4" suggests. And the `@foo.bars` somehow expected a `Foo::Bar`, which it doesn't anymore so I guess there was something wrong with a config or with somethings else. Anyhow, thanks!